# What is a good "unreachable" Error for switches?

Tags: java, exception, jls

Eclipse forces me to use a `default` case for any `switch` including those listing all declared `enum` values, allegedly because of the language specification [[1](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-ensuring_switch_completeness.htm)]. This is unfortunate because Android Studio, in which the project is developed in parallel, does not, and would naturally warn me about all `switch`es which become incomplete if ever the `enum` is changed. While I would prefer the latter behaviour because the former makes `enum` changes actually *more* error-prone (see example below), I am in no position to choose, so I need to find how to do this right for both. I suppose if there is a place in a code which should under any circumstances remain unreachable but still removing the line is not an option, throwing an `Error` seems like the natural thing to do there. But which one, is there a generally accepted subclass for such a scenario (perhaps extending to other "forced" unreachable places)? Or is it acceptable to simply throw a quick-and-dirty `new Error("enum name")` just for the sake of it, instead of writing my own just to be never used?

In the example:

```
public static enum Color {
    RED,
    GREEN,
    BLUE;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        switch(this) {
            case RED:
                return "Red";
            case GREEN:
                return "Green";
            case BLUE:
                return "Blue";
            default:
                /* never reached */
                throw new ThisCanNeverHappenError();
        }
    }
}
```

adding `WHITE` to the `enum` makes this `switch` and possibly many more throughout the code silent sources of nasty errors as flow control finds them to be just fine.

Comment: If you define your own you can use whatever you want, but you probably want to subclass `RuntimeException` because you don't want to have `throws` specification for exception that should never happen.

Comment: This is a perfect example of how *not* to use a conditional. Use polymorphism instead and make the string a property of the enum instance.

Comment: @skyking: I read that `Error` is not checked, so as not to encourage people to catch it.

Comment: @chrylis: Sorry, I'm lost: what does a property of an enum instance mean? And how is polymorphism used if `enum`s can't be extended?

Comment: @TheVee you can define the instances like `RED("Red")` and add a constructor `private Color(String name)` to assign the parameter to a field - and then return that field in `toString()`.

Comment: `Error` is not checked *because it means something completely different*. And it seems like perhaps you're only familiar with C-style enums; read the official tutorial on Java enums. This is clearly explained with understandable examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not throw an `Error`. A better exception should be `IllegalStateException`:

```
switch(this) {
    case RED:
        return "Red";
    case GREEN:
        return "Green";
    case BLUE:
        return "Blue";
    default:
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected enum value: " + this.name());
}
```

---

On a different note, you shouldn't use a `switch` statement there anyway. Add a field to the enum. Also note that enums are always `static`, so you can remove that keyword.

```
public enum Color {
    RED  ("Red"),
    GREEN("Green"),
    BLUE ("Blue");

    private final String displayText;

    private Color(String displayText) {
        this.displayText = displayText;
    }
    public String getDisplayText() {
        return this.displayText;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.displayText;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There was a LONG discussion of this in the [Eclipse Bugzilla/Bug 374605](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=374605).

The end result is that this is a configurable warning and can be disabled.

[image]

Change the dropdown from Warning to Ignore

Answer (score 1):

Throwing `Error`s is not a very wise move - most exception-handling code passes them thru, they end up in strange places, might make your process unusable.

I would recommend `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: *"wise movie"* Did you perhaps mean *move*?

Comment: Passing them through was more or less the intention – this is a bug so serious that I don't want the program to attempt at any recovery and unconditionally give me the stack trace. Also, observing it is enough reason to try and check every occurrence of the cause, preventing that from happening in production.

Comment: @TheVee If it does not happen you don't care whether it's Exception or Error, if it does happen you better have Exception there.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for this switch (and the corresponding handling of the default case) if you add the "toString" value as a parameter of the enum instances:

```
public static enum Color {
    RED("Red"),
    GREEN("Green"),
    BLUE("Blue");

    private final String name;

    private Color(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making an assertion: `/* never reached */` - if that assertion is erroneous you should probably throw an `AssertionError`.

The alternative recommendation of throwing an `IllegalStateException` is not really appropriate - according to the javadoc:

> Signals that a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time

which is not really the case here.